# Create Visual Studio 2010 extension to generate compiler warning

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, vsix

I want to create an extension to recognize specific comments in my code. I will use this to signal code smells by using the `//@` comment prefix. One feature of this extension will be to generate warnings for each comment encountered while compiling the code. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you need this functionality or you want to practice creating an extension? `#warning` might help you in first case.

Comment: "for each comment encountered in the compiled code" - that doesn't sound right. Either there's a misunderstanding of what "comment" and/or "compiled" means, or that wording needs some decent editing.

Comment: @Snowbear: I actually need it, it will help me manage better these items. This feature is only one of many.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I've updated the wording; this is what I'm after: I don't actually want to interfere with the compilation process, just add extra information, and enforce members of the team to pay more attention to the problems flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can hook into the compiler to generate warning. However, the "Error List" view aggregates errors, warnings and messages from multiple sources. Would it be good enough for you to simply append to that list?

Here's a link I could find on the subject : http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008022.aspx

Comment: At first glance, it looks like it would be possible to do exactly what I want: "Use the OutputWindowPane.OutputTaskItemString method, which not only writes to the output window pane but to the Error List too." The article is specific to VS 2005/2008, but it might point me in the right direction.

Comment: Here is an interesting article: "Walkthrough: Integrating into the Properties Window, Task List, Output Window, and Options Dialog Box (Part 4 of 4)" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138529.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample called CodeSweep that detects certain strings in comments (it is written to look for mild swear words) that adds tasks to your Task List. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Code-Sweep-3bfb7bb5 Reading this code could help you write your own extension if you can't use it as-is.

You could also use the existing task functionality and add your own keywords (like the out-of-the-box `//HACK` and `//TODO` - you could add `//SMELL`) which is quicker but gives you less control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2(v=VS.100).aspx. This may be all you need.